# Boolen check if datetime.now() is between the values of any tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: boolean-logic, python-3.7

I have a list of tuples looking like this:

```
import datetime as dt
hours = [(dt.datetime(2019,3,9,23,0), dt.datetime(2019,3,10,22,0)),
        (dt.datetime(2019,3,10,23,0), d.datetime(2019,3,11,22,0))]
```

The list has a variable length and I just need a boolean if `datetime.now()` is between the first and second element of any tuple in the list.
In `NumPy` I would do:

```
((start <= now) & (end >= now)).any()
```

what is the most efficient way to do this in a pythonic way? Sorry about the beginners question.

this works but I don't like the `len()`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x[0] <= now and now <= x[1], hours ))) > 0
```

any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
any(map(lambda d: d[0] <= now <= d[1], hours))
```

- any: Logical OR across all elements
- map: runs a function on every element of the list

As @steff pointed out map is redundant, because we cause list enumeration directly.

```
    any(d[0] <= now <= d[1] for d in hours)
```

It would be way better if we can avoid indexing into tuple and use tuple unpacking somehow (this was the reason I started with map)

Comment: works beautifully. thanks very much very that. Have a great weekend!

Comment: actually there is something wrong. only works if there are exactly two tuples in the list. If only one tuple:
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'

Comment: @steff, yes fixed it, but at the expense of being less pythonic I guess.

Comment: thanks vm. actually using this now:
`any(d[0] <= now <= d[1] for d in hours)`

Comment: @steff much better.

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose alternative. (But more readable in my eyes)

```
import datetime as dt


def in_time_ranges(ranges):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    return any([r for r in ranges if now <= r[0] and r[1] >= now])


ranges1 = [(dt.datetime(2019, 3, 9, 23, 0), dt.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 22, 0)),
           (dt.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 23, 0), dt.datetime(2019, 3, 11, 22, 0)),
           (dt.datetime(2019, 4, 10, 23, 0), dt.datetime(2019, 5, 11, 22, 0))]

print(in_time_ranges(ranges1))

ranges2 = [(dt.datetime(2017, 3, 9, 14, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 22, 0)),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 23, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 3, 11, 22, 0)),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 4, 10, 23, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 5, 11, 22, 0))]

print(in_time_ranges(ranges2))
```

Output

```
True
False
```